# Elastic Beanstalk maintain the changes made directly via ssh for new instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, instance

When the app autoscale, the previous modifications made in first instance will be kept in new instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add configuration settings to your application archive so that each instance is configured the same way when it is brought online.  This is done by creating a folder in your application called .ebextensions.  You place files in that folder with the .config extenstion.  These should be yaml format.

Check these docs for more information:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers.html

Linux specific (I assume Linux since you mention SSH):
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html

Answer (score 1):

No, elastic beanstalk will start a new server using a fresh AMI and your latest deployed application code.
It is considered bad practice to change the instance using SSH login, as it may be replaced at any time by Elastic Beanstalk.
If you'd like to change something in the instance, you can either use a custom AMI (not fun) or create an `.ebextensions` folder and put some configuration shell scripts there (see [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers.html)).